# Streaming RTMPE in App

Tags: java, android, rtmp

I am trying to stream a video in app using the native player for android. But when trying to stream a link with "rtmpe://" it doesn't work. Can anyone guide me on how to play this? So far  I have only seen solutions of iOS. I want to play this without using external Apps.

Comment: Check supported media formats for Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check supported media formats for Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Not all protocols work on android.

Comment: Is there any way to play this other than using native player for android? I've tried entering the link in the browser but it doesn't seem to work also.